# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages while installing libgl1-mesa-dev for qt

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, qt, qt5

I ran `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev` and received the error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed    
Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.65) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at the version numbers:

- 11.2.0 is in Ubuntu 16.04
- 17.0.7 is in Ubuntu 17.04

You seem to be trying to mix repositories from **two different releases of Ubuntu**. Never do that, unless you are an expert. It will break your package management. In fact, that's exactly what it looks like it did to your system.

**How to fix it**:

- Delete all sources from the other release of Ubuntu
- Uninstall all packages that you installed from those wrong-version sources

Depending upon what you already installed, there may be no easy way to undo the damage. It requires patience and hard work by you...or a complete reinstall.

Comment: I'll be needing to do a complete reinstall it seems, will try to reinstall those repositories first, thanks for the quick response