# It safe to install clang-6.0 from Debian repositories?

Tags: firefox, debian, clang

It safe to install `clang-6.0` via Debian official repositories?. I see the file is "likely" broken and risky by Firefox browser.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; but I do see `clang` 6.0 & other versions available in Ubuntu repositories so you don't need to use foreign Debian repos.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: never mix and match debian and ubuntu OSes.  It will introduce breakages to your system.  You also dont state what OS you use, so this is potentially offtopic anyways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages while installing libgl1-mesa-dev for qt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987818/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-while-installing-li)