# At work, "sudo apt update", "git clone", "npm install" errors do not occur, but at home, certificate-related errors occur

Tags: ssl, npm

Usually at work, I don't get any certificate related errors. However, when I try to execute "sudo apt update", "git clone", "npm install", etc. at home, an error occurs. I know it is probably something to do with the proxy, but I have not been able to solve the problem at all. I want to solve this problem for sure. Please help me.

```
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: ]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: ]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried the following items, but the error was not cured.
Go to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/.
Create a new folder." sudo mkdir school"
Copy the .crt file to the school folder.
Make sure permissions are OK (755 for folders, 644 for files).
Run "sudo update-ca-certificates".

Comment: Your sources have a problem. You have sources both from 20.04 and 22.04 in your sources file. You need to remove the the OS you are not using. Since you did not say what OS you are using I can not be more precise then that.

Comment: I originally used ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded my version to ubnutu 22.04 today. However, this error has been occurring since ubuntu 20.04, so I don't think it is an OS problem.

Comment: You need to remove the lines for version 20.04 from the file. If it has nothing to do with Ubuntu why ask it here?

Comment: If you look at the docker info itself, for 22.04 you should be using the Jammy repo and have the correct keyring gpg installed.  They do it this way now since apt-key is now deprecated.  Follow through their instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and you should be able to fix the error.  You shouldn't need to reinstall your docker, but it will probably want to update the version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages while installing libgl1-mesa-dev for qt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987818/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-while-installing-li)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.